About installing Wine on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I would like to install Wine on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. I am confused about the version that I should choose. There is a Debian package and a Snap application which is called "wine-platform-runtime". Which one should I install?
Best regards,
Nikos Lagios.

the phrasing of your question asks people to express an opinion which makes it off topic on Ask Ubuntu. These are the two references you should be looking at when making your choice. Ubuntu Handbook for debian and snapcraft for the snap package. If that raises specific questions, [edit] your question accordingly to save it being closed as off topic.

This question is similar to: How to install and configure Wine?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
